# how to display submit success/error message just above the contact form using bootstrap alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer

Here is my php code. Emails are delivered successfully. All I want to do is display the success or error msg just above the contact form.

```
    <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mes = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {

    // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                
    $mail->Host = '';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = '';               
    $mail->Password = '';                           
    // $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         
    $mail->Port = 25;                                  


    $mail->setFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
    $mail->addAddress('', '');   

    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);



    $mail->isHTML(true);                               
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();


    $mes = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Thank You! I will be in touch</div>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $mes = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>";
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

}
```

Here is my HTML form. PHP code is in the controller folder. Message is also displayed. I just want to redirect and display the message on the same page.
Do I need javascript?

```
<div class="row">
                    <?php 

                    if(isset($mes)){

                        echo "$mes";
                    }

                    ?>
                    <form action="ADMIN/controller/mail_send.php" method="POST" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" autocomplete="on" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" autocomplete="on" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" autocomplete="on" id="name" placeholder="Subject">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" class="form-control textarea" rows="3" name="Message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn main-btn pull-right">Send a message <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" id="send_image"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: you just need to echo `$mes`. Did you pass the var to your view file?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Message is also displayed . I just want to redirect and display the message on the same page

Comment: any `header()` call must come before any output, including whitespace

Comment: @delboy1978uk I dont get it. Do i need to add javascript?

Comment: what do you actually want? the question was how to display the message, but you say it is already displaying, and now you want a redirect?

Comment: Hello @deeva,  you should use ajax for it!